# How can I merge different data sets in R knowing that the variable that I use for matching the two data set are not unique?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dataset

I have two datasets, and I need to merge them by the ID value. The problems are:

1. The ID value can be repeated across the same dataset (no other unique value is available).
2. The two datasets are not equal in the rows number or the column numbers.

Example:

df1

| ID | Gender |
| --- | --- |
| 99 | Male |
| 85 | Female |
| 7 | Male |

df2

| ID | Body_Temperature | Body_Temperature_date_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | 36 | 1/1/2020 12:00 am |
| 99 | 38 | 2/1/2020 10:30 am |
| 99 | 37 | 1/1/2020 06:41 am |
| 52 | 38 | 1/2/2020 11:00 am |
| 11 | 39 | 4/5/2020 09:09 pm |
| 7 | 35 | 9/8/2020 02:30 am |

How can I turn these two datasets into one single dataset in a way that allows me to apply some machine learning models on it later on?

Comment: does the ID in df1 repeat too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your expected results, if you are wanting to return all rows from each dataframe, then you can use a `full_join` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(df2, df1, by = "ID")
```

Or with base R:

```
merge(x=df2,y=df1,by="ID",all=TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
  ID Body_Temperature Body_Temperature_date_time Gender
1 99               36          1/1/2020 12:00 am   Male
2 99               38          2/1/2020 10:30 am   Male
3 99               37          1/1/2020 06:41 am   Male
4 52               38          1/2/2020 11:00 am   <NA>
5 11               39          4/5/2020 09:09 pm   <NA>
6  7               35          9/8/2020 02:30 am   Male
7 85               NA                       <NA> Female
```

If you have more than 2 dataframes to combine, which only overlap with the `ID` column, then you can use `reduce` on a dataframe list (so put all the dataframes that you want to combine into a list):

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list <- list(df1, df2)

multi_full <- reduce(df_list, function(x, y, ...)
  full_join(x, y, by = "ID", ...))
```

Or `Reduce` with base R:

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2)

multi_full <- Reduce(function(x, y, ...)
    merge(x, y, by = "ID", all = TRUE, ...), df_list)
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(99L, 85L, 7L), Gender = c("Male", "Female", 
"Male")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(99L, 99L, 99L, 52L, 11L, 7L), Body_Temperature = c(36L, 
38L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 35L), Body_Temperature_date_time = c("1/1/2020 12:00 am", 
"2/1/2020 10:30 am", "1/1/2020 06:41 am", "1/2/2020 11:00 am", 
"4/5/2020 09:09 pm", "9/8/2020 02:30 am")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: what if i have 19 datasets !!! does it work like full_join(df2, df1,... df19 by = "ID"). and i am not sure if this new data structure is correct for applying ML models? or should i consider another appropriate way for aggregating my data........thanks

Comment: @MohammadAbd I just added an additional part to the answer. You can use `full_join` or `merge`, but you will need to put your dataframes into a list, then use a reduce function (as shown above). Whether that is the format that you need for ML models; I'm unsure without knowing more about the specifics (so would probably need to be a new question on here if you have specific questions on format for the ML model).

Comment: I have tried the two approaches, but i got the following:  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512.0 Mb

Comment: @MohammadAbd That's really dependent on a lot of other factors, like the machine that you are running it on, the size of all the dataframes that you trying to combine, etc. Sometimes you can solve it by increasing `memory.limit()`. But I would consider whether you need every single column from each dataframe. If you don't, then you might want to remove those columns prior to merging/joining them together.